# Laravel-5: Can't get Auth::attempt to succeed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My app.php

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Authentication Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
    | This driver manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
    | attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'database',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
    | is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
    |
    */

    'model' => 'App\Model\Member',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
    | default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'members',
```

My Model:

class Member extends Model implements Authenticatable {

```
protected $fillable = [];

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'members';

protected $primaryKey = 'id';

/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();

}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberToken()
{
    // TODO: Implement getRememberToken() method.
}

/**
 * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @param  string $value
 * @return void
 */
public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    // TODO: Implement setRememberToken() method.
}

/**
 * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    // TODO: Implement getRememberTokenName() method.
}
```

}

trying to Auth:attempt(....

```
 if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Request::input('email'), 'password' => Request::input('password'))))
            {
                echo ("SUCCESS");
                Auth::logout();
            }
            else
            {
                echo ("FAILED");
            }
```

This always gets "FAILED". If I do a `Member::where....`  search I will get the record correctly so I know the model and database are okay.

Why is Auth::attempt failing? I am making sure the emails and password are correct and present on the database.

Comment: just to be sure try making a change to config/auth.php and set 'table' = 'members' and see if it works then

Comment: Have you properly hashed the password?

Comment: I believe that is the problem. I did not use any password hashing thinking it would be the simplest case. I was wrong. When I do save passwords with Hash::make(.....) the Auth::attempt works.

Comment: user2094178 if you submit this as an answer I'll credit you. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Auth::attempt()` requires the password stored in the database to be hashed using `Hash::make($password)` or `bcrypt($password)`.